# UILocalNotification repeatInterval breaks timeZone and fireDate

Tags: ios, swift

I'm scheduling a batch of notifications in my app, some with repeat intervals, others just single fires at a specific date. I'm setting my notifications using this method to create the notifications:

```
func notification(date: Date, repeatUnit: NSCalendar.Unit?) -> UILocalNotification {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.category = "ReminderCategory"
    notification.alertTitle = "Test"
    notification.alertBody = "Test Body"
    notification.soundName = "Sound1.m4a"
    notification.fireDate = date
    notification.repeatInterval = repeatUnit ?? NSCalendar.Unit(rawValue: 0)
    notification.timeZone = TimeZone.init(secondsFromGMT: 0)!

    return notification
}
```

The notifications fire at the correct times (for the local timezone) if the `repeatUnit` variable is set to be any of the `NSCalendar.Unit` units.

However, if I don't set a `repeatInterval`, the notifications fireDates are somehow set in the past and they fire as soon as I schedule the notifications.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: If you compare `date` do `Date.date()`, is `date` in the past?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Title"
    content.body = "Your text"
    content.categoryIdentifier = "reminder-notification"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()


    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date)
    dateComponents.minute = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
```